# Xamarin: Does a Collection.Remove in List remove the wrong object?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have the strange behaviour in the list view in user's devices which I can't find the same issue on our devices in android written in Xamarin form.

I have a list view which bound with a IList objects in the list collection. Each items inside list view have a command which once clicked the item will be removed from the list.

To remove the item inside the collection, I used Collection.Remove(model). The Collection is a list which stored all ViewModel shown inside the list view and the model are the viewModel got from the Collection.

```
public ICommand OnAcceptCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async (param) =>
            {
                await App.GlobalLayout.PreventMultiClicking(null, async () =>
                {
                    var model = param as HeadCountLineViewModel;
                    var result = await model.ToggleAccounted(true);

                    if (result)
                        Collection.Remove(model);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

The param is the model from the Collection passed by the item inside the list view.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="phoneTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame HasShadow="false" Padding="{StaticResource cellPadding}">
                    <local:ExtendedFrame Style="{StaticResource cardStyle}" BackgroundColor="{Binding HeadCountLineStatus, Converter={StaticResource accountedToColorConverter}}">

                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" RowSpacing="5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition> 
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <controls:CircleImage
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="0"
                                Style="{StaticResource profileImageStyle}"
                                Source="{Binding Source}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"> 
                            </controls:CircleImage>

                            <Label 
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                x:Name="childName" 
                                Text="{Binding ChildName}" 
                                Style="{StaticResource MediumBoldFont}" 
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="Center">
                            </Label>

                            <Image
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Style="{StaticResource listviewButtonStyle}"
                                IsVisible="{Binding IsUnAccounted, Converter={StaticResource invertConverter}}"
                                Source="ic_action_undo.png"
                                HorizontalOptions="End">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="OnUndoTapped" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image 
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                IsVisible="{Binding IsUnAccounted}"
                                Style="{StaticResource listviewButtonStyle}"
                                Source="ic_action_yes.png"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"> 
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Tapped="OnAcceptedTapped">
                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Image.Margin>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>0, 0, 5, 0</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>5, 5, 20, 5</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Image.Margin>
                            </Image>
                            <Image
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                IsVisible="{Binding IsUnAccounted}"
                                Style="{StaticResource listviewButtonStyle}"
                                Source="ic_action_no.png"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="End">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Tapped="OnAbsentTapped">
                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Image.Margin>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>5, 0, 0, 0</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>20, 5, 5, 5</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Image.Margin>
                            </Image>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                                <local:ChildInfoIconsView 
                                    ShowClassroom="false"
                                    Child="{Binding Child}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                                </local:ChildInfoIconsView>
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage 
                                    LoadingDelay="2000"
                                    WidthRequest="24"
                                    HeightRequest="24"
                                    x:Name="ImageClassroom"
                                    Source="ic_location"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding HasClass}">
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                                <Label
                                    Style="{StaticResource NormalFont}"
                                    Text="{Binding Class}"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding HasClass}">
                                </Label>
                                <Label  
                                    x:Name="note" 
                                    Text="{Binding Note, StringFormat='Absent Note : {0}'}" 
                                    Style="{StaticResource SmallFont}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsNoteVisible}">
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout> 

                        </Grid>

                    </local:ExtendedFrame>
                </Frame>        
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
```

In the page:

```
void OnAcceptedTapped (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Image && ((Image)sender).BindingContext is HeadCountLineViewModel)
        {
            var model = ((Image)sender).BindingContext as HeadCountLineViewModel;
            var vModel = BindingContext as ShowAllHeadCountLinesViewModel;
            vModel.OnAcceptCommand.Execute(model);
        }
    }
```

From the first code, I have a Collection.Remove. By any chance wrong model got removed. Visually from user's video, the removed cell looks like it get removed but leaving the Child's name in the removed cell unchanged where other visual element updated e.g. Source.

Comment: It looks like the item did remove correctly. Is the views of the item not rendered correctly on android. The ios device work's fine

Comment: I think the problem lie within CacheStrategy. If I use RecycleElement , the problem solved.